# Does the finalize function in mongoDB mapReduce processes different keys in parallel?

Tags: mongodb

I've check the documentation and it doesn't mention anything about it, I'm curious of how this works. it's javascript code, which I think mongoDB mapReduce runs on single core. but not sure about parallelism/threads.

Finalize function it's similar to the reduce function but runs after. Does the reduce function runs in parallel for different keys?

Comment: What is a finalize function? Do you mean "reducer"?

Comment: There is a finalize function in mapReduce, it's similar to the reduce function but runs after. Does the reduce function runs in parallel for different keys?